# Limit of multiplicative depth in leveled fully homomorphic encryption

Tags: cryptography

Is there any practical estimate of the maximum multiplicative depth D that is supported by leveled FHE schemes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to software development. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.